How to change string format to date format in particular columns in Sas
I have a dataset which has 100 columns. A simpler & smaller version is as follows:



Account
Anticipated_Close_Date
Need_Date
Amount
Date_Accepted
Confirmed_Date
Comments




John
1/15/2024
1/15/2024
1000


Awaiting Acceptance


John
1/23/2024
1/28/2024
20000
1/20/2024
1/22/2024
Closed


Sam
12/25/2023







Peter
4/5/2024
4/12/2024
350
3/27/2024

Confirmation needed



The dataset has around 30 columns with various dates all in character format. I need to convert all of them into date format.
Also, the number of columns with date information can change i.e there can be new addition or deletion.
I know:
data want;
set database;
format temp mmddyy10.;
temp = input(Anticipated_Close_Date, mmddyy10.);
drop Anticipated_Close_Date;
rename temp = Anticipated_Close_Date;


will give me the desired format. I have also identified all columns having 'Date' in them:
proc contents data = database out= contents noprint; run;

proc sql;
select name into :varlist seperated by ' '
from contents
where name like '%Date%';
quit;

I do not how to combine them both and run it over the entire dataset. My guess is we need to iterate over each column and check if the column is a part of 'varlist' and if true, use the input function.

You can use the :varlist to specify the elements of a DATA Step array and loop over the array.  You will need to have some more SQL :into to create other code snippets needed to convert and rename.
Example:
Variables named *Date* are character strings and the same name should be used after converting the string to a SAS date value.
proc contents data = database out= contents noprint; run;

proc sql;
select 
  cats(quote(trim(name),"'"),'N=_',varnum)
, cats('_',varnum)
, cats(quote(trim(name),"'"),'N')
into
  :rename_in separated by ' '
  :temp_date_vars separated by ' '
  :date_vars separated by ' '
from contents
where name like '%Date%';
quit;

data want ;
  set database (rename=(&rename_in)) ;
  array tempdates &temp_date_vars ;
  array dates &date_vars ;
  do over dates ;
    dates = input(tempdates,mmddyy10.) ;
  end ;
  format &date_vars mmddyy10. ;
run;


Thanks for answering. Your solution is giving me an error after set database (rename=&rename_in); saying " Expecting a=." followed by a bunch of "Invalid option name". Any idea how to resolve this?

Oops, the rename= option list should be in parenthesis.  Edited answer. Docs - https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/ledsoptsref/p1pczmnhbq4axpn1l15s9mk6mobp.htm

I am still getting the "Expecting a=." for 'Account:_Last_Date' and getting a syntax error for Date_Funded/Closed. I think its because of ':' & '/' characters. Is there any workaround for this, if possible?

Where is the data coming from ? Is session option VALIDVARNAME=ANY set? It must be if Proc CONTENTS is presenting a variable name Account:_Last_Date which contains a :.  Example edited to work with variable name literals
